# images in emails using roadie gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to know how to show images in email by using roadie gem. Using roadie i'm able to inline my stylesheets but it's not showing images. I have tried both

```
<%= image_tag "pic.jpg" %>
```

and

```
<img src="pic.jpg"/> or <img src="assets/images/pic.jpg"/>
```

inside my mail template, but it's not showing any of the images. Any help?

Comment: This seems to be a bug with the gem `https://github.com/Mange/roadie-rails/issues/10`

Comment: @bcackerman thanks! i actually ended up dropping the idea of using it and  went for conventional and boring way of making email templates :)

Comment: Nice yeah it seems you need to make sure to set `config.action_mailer.asset_host`

Comment: @Mandeep did you ever get this working with `roadie-rails`? Thanks!

Comment: @jackerman09 just posted an answer, check it out and let me know if that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I asked this question and I was pretty new to rails development so didn't really know what I was doing wrong. Anyways so the issue is ***when we use image_tag helper or asset_path helpers for rendering images, it makes relative paths for that image***(you can check it in firebug or some other tool) and they won't work inside emails or lets say on any other remote server (other than where the app is hosted)

**Fix:**

You can specify where your assets are hosted by:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://your_server.com'
```

Answer (score -1):

Quite old, but if somebody needs this...

Usually I use:

```
%img{:src => asset_url('/email/logo.png') }
```

also, as mentioned in the comments, be sure to have `config.action_mailer.asset_host` configured

example: 
`config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000/assets/"`