# Rails 4 Mailer Images are not getting displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, mailer

I am using roadie-rails gem for mailers. Here is my simple code to display image in mail

```
 <td style="padding-left:25px; padding-top:15px;">
   <%= image_tag( 'school_mailers/mail_2_logo.png' ) %>
 </td>
```

But when i inspect the image url in mail it is https://staging.pw/images/school_mailers/mail_2_logo.png

instead it should be https://staging.pw/assets/school_mailers/mail_2_logo-digest.png

The thing is when i send scheduled mailers using whenever gem, the mail is perfect with all images.

Does anybody have an idea about why its not displayed in other mailers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is with assets precompilation,

I do have two servers( web and worker ). All assets have been precompiled only in web server. So 'whenever' gem sends mail from web server and delayed_job sends from worker server.

Adding below in deploy.rb made it work

```
set :assets_roles, [:web, :worker]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified assets_host in your config?

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://staging.pw/assets/'
```

More in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609089/images-in-emails-using-roadie-gem).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have resolved it and posted solution for it